# Are these input jacks the same?

Tags: input

Apologies for the dumb question. I am wondering if these two input jacks the same. Here's a stereo 1/4" jack designed for a guitar with active pickups:

https://www.realparts.com.au/electronics/jacks/switchcraft-1-4-stereo-jack.html

It it the same as this?

https://www.jaycar.com.au/6-5mm-stereo-insulated-unswitched-socket/p/PS0192

I'm not sure what "Open switch type (closed when plug is NOT inserted)." means.

Comment: It means that the plug includes a switch, which is normally closed, until you insert a plug. More details should be supplied by the seller, not us.

Comment: Well they are certainly not the same part. Or do you mean do they work the same? The best thing to do if you are unsure is look at a datasheet for the part. If the site selling the component does not have a datasheet, go to a more reputable seller for your components. This goes for all, not just jacks

Comment: The biggest difference --without looking at specs-- appears to be "insulated" vs "not insulated" (the plastic barrel).  This may be important if mounted in a metal hole.  There may be other important differences also.

Comment: They're not the same part - one has switch built in to detect a plug being inserted (e.g. for automatically switching between headphones and speakers). Whether they're close enough to work the same in your application depends on whether you need that capability.